# Pre-populating Model Form with object data - Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have tried various options for this but no luck so far. I am trying to get instance data to be pre-populated into my ModelField. Here is what I have:

forms.py

```
class edit_project_info(ModelForm):
    project_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150)


class Meta:
    model = Project
    exclude = ['project_type', 'created_date', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'pm_scope', 'dev_scope', 'design_scope', 'testing_scope' ]
```

View.py

```
def edit_project (request, offset):
    this_project = Project.objects.get(pk=offset)
    data = {'project_name' : 'abc'}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = edit_project_info(request.POST, instance=this_project, initial=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/project_profile/%s/' % offset)
    else:
        form = edit_project_info()
```

All I get is an empty field. I can add the initial value to forms.py, but then it is static rather than populated based on the form instance. What I have done here with creating a dict and then passing it to initial in the form instance does not seem to do anything. I'm sure I am missing something basic. Any help would be great! Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Two last lines recreate your `form` variable. Just remove `else: form = edit_project_info()`:

```
def edit_project (request, offset):
    this_project = Project.objects.get(pk=offset)
    data = {'project_name' : 'abc'}
    form = edit_project_info(request.POST, instance=this_project, initial=data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/project_profile/%s/' % offset)
    # else:
    #     form = edit_project_info()
    # ...
```

Comment: This gives me an error "local variable 'form' referenced before assignment" but based on your suggestion I changed the last line to "form = edit_project_info(initial=data)" and it works as expected now. Still need to do a little research to understand why. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't understand indents. I updated the answer - the `form` should be before `if request.method == 'POST':`.